How to set correct parameters for x264 lib
I depacketize the H264 video fragments from an IP.RTP stream and save them to video.ivf file. After depacketizing i have only [SPS] ,[PPS] and [non-IDR slice]. I try to create IDR slice by using x264 lib. x264 lib creates IDR frame which consists of 0x000001[SPS nal type 7] 0x000001[PPS nal type 8] 0x0001[SE slice nal type 6] and 0x0001[I slice nal type 5]. How to set correct parameters for x264 lib if i have real SPS and PPS frames to get the same SPS and PPS frames
i parse SPS and PPS but i don't know which parameters of x264_param_t param i should set.
can someone give me some examples.

Actually you need to change the way you work with stream. As I understood, you are trying inject own generated IDR packet into existing stream with original P-frame packets, it won't work even if you have SPS PPS, because original P-frames are linked to original I-frame packet, but not to generated by your code. And libx264 does not provide a way for pre-heat encoder with existing SPS/PPS (honestly I don't know any encoder which can do that, and seems this is not possible).
You can solve the problem through 2 ways:

Skip all P-frames before first received I-frame, then save SPS/PPS/IDR and all next P-frames. In this case you don't need encoder, but your output file or stream will have the same IDR frequency as original stream
Complete transcoding: feed H.264 decoder with input stream and re-encode with libx264 with your parameters. In this case you will lost stream before first I-frame too, because it is required for start decoding in any case, but you can setup own IDR frequency as need

